# Difference between CHAR(n) FOR BIT DATA and BINARY(n)?

Tags: db2, db2-luw, db2-11.5

I think I have seen somewhere that there is some sort of semantic difference between `CHAR(n) FOR BIT DATA` and `BINARY(n)`, but I'm unable to locate where it was. Any pointers?

I'm asking because I have loads of columns defined as `CHAR(16) FOR BIT DATA` from before `BINARY(16)` existed, and thinking about gradually migrate them to BINARY(16). I'm curious whether there are any circomstances where migrating one side of a f.k. relationship before the other will cause problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference I believe is described at the [Casting between data types](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=types-casting-between-data) link (see Table 1). For example, you can't cast BINARY data to/from many data types which it's possible to cast CHAR FOR BIT DATA to/from. So, it's more an application part problem, and one should check if their apps use such a casting or not.
That is, if you, say, store UUIDs as the result of the `GENERATE_QNIQUE ()` function  returning `CHAR (13) FOR BIT DATA` and use these values as an argument to the `TIMESTAMP` function, then you have to rewrite you code from `TIMESTAMP (MY_BIT_COL)` to `TIMESTAMP (MY_BIT_COL :: CHAR (13) FOR BIT DATA)`.